# Twitter POST direct_messages/new api not working

Tags: php, api, twitter

I am using POST direct_messages/new for inviting twitter friends for my website.

About a month ago, my application could send direct messages, but now the API is returning this error:

> > "This request looks like it might be automated. To protect our users from spam and other malicious activity, we can't complete this action right now. Please try again later."

How can I fix this error to continue sending direct messages from my application??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems that Twitter blocks DM (via their API).
If I'm not mistaken, you still can use DMs without links.

Comment: Sorry but DM means ???

Comment: DM stands for Direct Message @Simranjeet

Comment: Does you direct message contains any url? If yes you can check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/25308717/2246798

Answer (score 0):

According to Twitter's developer site you have to *[file a ticket](https://support.twitter.com/forms/platform)* if you get the message: *This request looks like it might be automated. To protect our users from spam and other malicious activity, we can’t complete this action right now.*

> We constantly monitor and adjust our filters to block spam and
>   malicious activity on the Twitter platform. These systems are tuned in
>   real-time. If you get this response our systems have flagged the Tweet
>   or DM as possibly fitting this profile. If you feel that the Tweet or
>   DM you attempted to create was flagged in error, please report the
>   details around that to us by filing a ticket at
>   https://support.twitter.com/forms/platform.

From [Twitter Developers Error Codes & Responses](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/response-codes) (the error codes list, error code 226)