# How to send URL to Friend in Twitter

Tags: ios, iphone, twitter

How can i send the URL to twitter friend in iOS.
I can send direct message but it does not allow me to send URL in it.

Here is my code for Posting Drirect message to Twitter Friend and its working.

```
-(void)postMessageToFriend:(NSString *)ID withMessage:(NSString *)message {

    NotificatioName = notificationNameStr;

    ACAccountType *accountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];
    [accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType options:nil completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {

        if (granted && !error) {

            NSArray *accountsListAry = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountType];

            int NoOfAccounts = [accountsListAry count];
            if (NoOfAccounts >0) {

                NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/direct_messages/new.json"];
                twitterAccount = [accountsListAry lastObject];

                NSDictionary *p =@{@"status":@"Posted",@"screen_name":ID, @"text":message};
                SLRequest *postRequest = [SLRequest  requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter requestMethod:SLRequestMethodPOST URL:url parameters:p];

                [postRequest setAccount:twitterAccount];
                [postRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResposnse, NSError *error){
                    if (error) {
                        NSLog(@"error : %@",error);
                    }else{
                        NSError *jsonError = nil;

                        NSString * responseStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted];

                        NSArray *friendsdata =
                        [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: [responseStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                                        options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                          error: &jsonError];
                        NSLog(@"response value is: %@ %d ",friendsdata,[urlResposnse statusCode]);

                    }
                }];
            }
        }
    }];
}
```

But If i try to add URL in my message than its return me this error

```
{
    errors =     (
                {
            code = 226;
            message = "This request looks like it might be automated. To protect our users from spam and other malicious activity, we can't complete this action right now. Please try again later.";
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: have you tried integrating instpaper's x-callback-url? http://blog.instapaper.com/post/4637427075

Comment: @RachelGallen how does that help?

Answer (score 4):

I think it has nothing to do with your code, but with Twitter. Apparently, they're not allowing to send links in direct messages. https://support.twitter.com/articles/14606-posting-or-deleting-direct-messages.

You can't do that even as a user from the official twitter client or from their website. AFAIK, it's a known issue and they're said to be working on it. But it's been long since they said that.

Comment: Thanx for Reply. Yes i have checked that. And also tried to send URL from Twitter site in direct message and it does not allow me that. But than there is anyway to send URL to friend other than that.

Comment: At the moment, I don't think there is a way to send a URL to a twitter follower / following, using the twitter API.

Comment: That is wrong Marius. You can totally send URLs in direct messages through the official Twitter application for iOS.

Comment: nst, I will check that out. I personally couldn't send a URL to a twitter friend (who I follow and he follows me back) even from the official Twitter client for mac. But I will try your library

Answer (score 0):

Your request is refused by Twitter because it is signed with OS X consumer tokens, as all instances of `SLRequest` are.

If you want to send URLs in direct messages, you have to sign your requests with the consumer tokens from an official Twitter client.

This cannot be done with SLRequest but can be done with third-party libraries such as [STTwitter](https://github.com/nst/STTwitter).

Answer (score 0):

It is not a proper answer but stil i am sharing it. In my case I have to share the link of my app in the direct message. Message with url in the message text doesn't work but link of any twitter account can be shared with the message text. So I made a twitter acc for my app and give the link there.